# Permutation cycle notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I'm trying to compute **(12)(1253)**

---

What I Did:

I started with 1, and 1 goes to 2 and 2 goes to one, so (12).
Then I did 5, which goes to 3.  3 goes to 1 and 1 goes to 2.  Then 2 goes to 5, so it's back around again.

What I Got:

(12)(532)

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks right to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we have $1 \to 2$ on (1 2 5 3). We then see on (1 2) that $2 \to 1$. So we have $(1)$ as our first cycle. We only write down a number if we start with it, or if we don't see it to the left of our current position.

Now start at $2$, so open $(2$. Note $2 \to 5$. We don't see $5$ again, so write down $5$: (2 5. Now start at $5$, which goes to $3$. We don't see $3$ again, so write down $3$: (2 5 3. Now start at $3$. We see $3 \to 1$, and then $1 \to 2$. We would write down $2$, except we started at $2$, so close the cycle. So we have (1)(2 5 3) = (2 5 3) as our answer.

Comment: That makes more sense.  Would there ever be the same number twice in the ( )?

Comment: No. When you multiply cycles, you get the product of disjoint cycles. So no two cycles in the final product will share the same number, and no cycle will have repeated elements.

Comment: Awesome, makes a lot more sense. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help!