# permutation cycle group of a large power

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I was going to add this to my previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712738/permutation-cycle-notation), but I didn't think that was allowed.

The question I have here:

(1254)^1000

---

How would I find something of this large?  Would I be able to do (1254)^4 and find it that way since 1000 is divisible by 4?

Comment: First of all you need to mention what group you are working on. Then find the order of the cycle $(1 \ 2 \ 5 \ 4)$. Then any power of the cycle times its order is just the identity element is what I suspect the answer should be.

Comment: Calculate the first few powers, and you will learn enough to write down the answer.

Comment: A cycle of length 4 has order 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, you can use $(1254)^4$.  In particular, we have
$$
(1254)^{1000} = ((1254)^{4})^{250} = ?
$$

Comment: Just curious, what if I had |(1254)|?  Would that change anything?

Comment: Have you tried calculating $(1254)^4$?  If so, then you should have $|(1254)|$.  Having that information in advance might save you the computation, but it comes down to the same process.

Comment: Yes I calculated that and got the identity.  Is || absolute value or some other meaning?

Comment: Why did you ask about it if you don't know what it means?  For an element $g$ of a group $G$, $|g|$ is the lowest (positive) exponent $n$ for which $g^n$ is the identity element.  So in this case, $|(1254)| = 4$.  What happens if you take the identity element, and multiply it by itself $250$ times?

Comment: Saw the || on many sites and wasn't exactly sure.  And you'd get 1 again right?

Comment: That's right, and so that's the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the element in a group, o(a), is the smallest positive integer such that $a^{n} = e_{G}$, the identity. The order of a cycle happens to be the number of elements it has. So o(1254) = 4. So let's work it out:

(1254)(1254) = (15)(24)

(15)(24)(1254) = (1452)

(1452)(1254) = (1)(2)(5)(4) = (1)

So here's a hint- think about rules of exponents. If you're familiar with modular arithmetic and Fermat's Little Theorem, all of that applies here.

Comment: Fixed the formatting. Sorry about that!

Comment: By the way, I don't think you should suggest Fermet's theorem. $1000 = 4 \times 250$ is all you need.

Comment: It may not necessary at this point, but I've found pulling from Number Theory to be helpful in learning algebra. If someone is familiar with it, hopefully it will help it click for them. Otherwise, they can ignore it and stick with exponentiation arguments.

Comment: I honestly find the reference to Fermat's theorem a little misleading. What you need here is simply $1000 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$. Also, it is probable that Fermat's theorem will be introduced to OP after he/she finishes learning about permutation groups.

Comment: What we get from Fermat's Little Theorem (and Lagrange's Theorem) is that for an element $a \in G$, if $a^{n} = e_{G}$, then $o(a)|n$. Not misleading at all!

Comment: I never heard of Fermat, but I googled it and I'm not too sure on that, so I stick with the first and try it.

Comment: Of course we can get a lot of things from Fermat's theorem. My point is the thing we need here can be obtained by much simpler methods. Mentioning Fermat's theorem here can be confusing to beginning students. (It does confuse me.)

Comment: That's a fair point. I came into Algebra with more Graph Theory and Number Theory, plus most math fluency courses teach modular arithmetic and basic number theory. People tend to like $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ since it's a familiar group, so I figure analogs to that may help someone. Hopefully my comment didn't create too much confusion. :-)